# Conditional Split Configuration for SSN with too many numbers

Tags: ssis

I have created a Conditional Split for a SSN column in my table. However, the syntax I used is not correct (it shows red).
How do I write the syntax to retain the first 9 numbers, and eliminate all numbers and or charatcers after the 9th digit?

The image shows what I did
[image]

Comment: Move mouse pointer over condition with error and stay there for two seconds, you will see detailed description.

Comment: You're missing a right parenthesis. You need one to close DT_STR, and one to close LEN.

Answer (score 0):

check this it will work

```
LEN(DT_STR(SSN,10,1252)))==9
```